# android bitmap gradient in android 2.1

Tags: android, bitmap, gradient

Is there a way to put a gradient to a bitmap object in android 2.1? The image must look like this:

[image: image with gradient]

I need the gradient only on top of the bitmap. DrawableGradient or LinearGradient are only from android 2.2 so these objects doesn't help me at all. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Do you need this from XML or from code?  In code, try this:

```
    /* Create a 200 x 200 bitmap and fill it with black. */
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

    /* Create your gradient. */
    LinearGradient grad = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 50, Color.GRAY, Color.BLACK, TileMode.CLAMP);

    /* Draw your gradient to the top of your bitmap. */
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    p.setShader(grad);
    c.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 50, p);
```

In XML, just make two separate views in a vertical linear layout.  The top view should have a gradient drawable background, the bottom, taller view should have a solid background.

Comment: but my image can be something with red or blue... it's not always the same image...

Comment: Why does your image color matter?  Aren't you just overlaying it on top of the gradient?

Comment: I have the same problem, the thing is that the gradient should be of the image, not an overlay of black/white on top of it to hide the image content. I want the bitmap to actually be transparent at one side and opaque on the other..

Comment: @Faraz - Open up a new question, link it here, and I'll answer how I'd do the transparent gradient thing.